# Google Cloud API - Get Policies For All Resources

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am trying to get the policies for all the resources so I can view the roles and members associated with them. Any method of getting all the policies through the API would work for me.

I am currently trying to list the organizations (resources) so that I can then get the policies for each resource with a command like GetIamPolicy. However, the organizations.list command returns null. Let me know if any of you have had success getting any policy.

I am using the C# API with a service key to connect to my Google Cloud account.

Comment: Turns out my account didn't have any organizations. Without organizations how can you get all the policies?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the list of all of your GCP Organization resources so that you can cycle through the list to get the IAM policy bindings for each organization.

**Get organizations from Cloud Resource Manager API:**

To accomplish this, you would first use `organizations.search` (with no filter) to get a list of all of your organizations.

*Try it [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/cloud%20resource%20manager/cloudresourcemanager/v1/cloudresourcemanager.organizations.search?_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%257D&) with the API Explorer.*

**Get organization IAM policy from the Cloud Resource Manager API.**

Then, for each organization, you would use the organization `name` to call `organizations.getIamPolicy` in order to get the IAM Policy for that organization.

*Try it [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/cloud%20resource%20manager/cloudresourcemanager/v1/cloudresourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy?resource=organizations%252F1234567890&resource=%257B%250A%257D&_h=3&) with the API Explorer (update the resource to reflect your organization name).*

---

*Note: IAM Policy is how you control access to resources in GCP. There are various levels at which you can manage IAM Policies, including organizations, folders and projects. There is a entirely separate concept called Org Policy, which allows you to control which API services can be enabled in each of your projects.*